# Unauthenticated error using gcloud-python to connect to google bigtable

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-bigtable

I've set up a Google Cloud BigTable cluster on my project.  The main codebase for the project runs within a standard Python App Engine environment, which can't use the gcloud-python library because of the reliance on grpcio.  To get around this, I've set up  a Python App Engine Flexible Environment service within the same project and written a very simple Flask server to run on it, which I can then hit from my standard environment.  The code looks something like this:

```
from gcloud import bigtable
app = Flask(__name__)

client = bigtable.Client(project=bigtable_config.PROJECT_ID, read_only=True)
cluster = client.cluster(bigtable_config.ZONE_ID, bigtable_config.CLUSTER_ID)
table = cluster.table(bigtable_config.TABLE_ID)

@app.route("/query/<start_key>/<end_key>")
def run_query(start_key, end_key):
    if not client.is_started():
        client.start()

    row_data = table.read_rows(start_key=start_key, end_key=end_key)
    row_data.consume_all()

    // do some stuff to the row data here, get results

    return jsonify(results)
```

I can run this code locally and it works great.  I can deploy it to my service and it continues to work great.  However, if the service sits idle for some period of time (I've typically noticed it after about an hour), then every request I make starts failing with this error:

```
NetworkError(code=StatusCode.UNAUTHENTICATED, details="Request had invalid authentication credentials.")
```

If I redeploy the service, it starts working again.  I do not observe this behavior when I'm running the service locally.

What am I doing wrong?  I'm assuming I'm making some mistake in my setup of the client, where it's not properly using the app engine credentials.  Do I need to kill the client and restart it when I encounter this error?

Comment: Last night, we released an updated Python client to PyPi 0.17.0.  It has been substantially updated.

Comment: There is an open issue https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-python/issues/1917 for this problem.

Comment: Awesome, I'll keep an eye out for updates.

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer in this case, as it's the correct thing to do, when the solution lies outside of the Q&A format, with issue tracking in another forum.

Comment: @HerbertLee can you weigh in on the GitHub issue? Can you confirm that the errors were on Python Flexible (which means the auth is using GCE tokens)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is being tracked at [github](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-python/issues/1917).